# How do i order by month when using the FORMAT function

Tags: sql, mysql, date, sql-order-by, yearmonth

I tried to do it but it keeps messing up the order for some reason. I tried DATE_FORMAT and it says it's not a recognized built-in function name

```
Select
  FORMAT(ProcessDate, 'MMM-yy') as ProcessDate,
  ProcessComment as ProcessComment
from EMPLOYEE
where ProcessDate between '23/06/2023' and '23/12/2023'
order by ProcessDate desc;
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: " I tried DATE_FORMAT and it says it's not a recognized built-in function name" - Then it's probably not MySQL that you are using. The function to convert a date into a string is `DATE_FORMAT` in MySQL. If this throws an error, then you are using some other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You convert the date into a string that is no longer sortable (DEC comes before FEB in the alphabet for instance). As you name the string the same as the original date, the DBMS thinks you want to sort by the string you have generated. Use an alias name that differs from the column name and sort by the original date.

You should also use proper date literals and not use strings that you hope the DBMS will convert correctly into dates for you (guessing which position is the day and which is the month for instance).

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT(processdate, 'MMM-yy') AS process_date,
  processcomment AS process_comment
FROM employee 
WHERE processdate BETWEEN DATE '2023-06-23' and DATE '2023-12-23' 
ORDER BY processdate DESC;
```

You seem to have been mistaken by tagging your request `mysql`. Look up the function that converts dates into strings in your DBMS. This may be `FORMAT`, `DATE_FORMAT`, `TO_CHAR`, or something else still. Look at the parameters, too, in order to use it correctly. As to date literals:Your DBMS may or may not support them. So this is another thing you may have to adjust.

Comment: Note that `ORDER BY processdate DESC` will not work properly if a second column is added to the ORDER BY.